# Jukito: How to instantiate Widget while testing view

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, jukito

I have Jukito test like this:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class HomeViewTest extends ViewTestBase {

  @Inject
  private HomeView homeView;

  public static class Module extends ViewTestModule {

    @Override
    protected void configureViewTest() {
      bind(HomeView.Binder.class).to(HomeTestBinder.class);
    }

    static class HomeTestBinder extends MockingBinder<Widget, HomeView> implements HomeView.Binder {

      @Inject
      public HomeTestBinder(final MockFactory mockitoMockFactory) {
        super(Widget.class, mockitoMockFactory);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In home view I'm creating new instance of widget HTML. Like this

```
final HTML connectToServer = new HTML();
```

But test fails with follow exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document.nativeGet()Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Document;
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document.nativeGet(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document.get(Document.java:46)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML.<init>(HTML.java:84)
```

I tried a `forceMock()` but it didn't help. Among this I tried to inject HTML in constructor through `com.google.inject.Provider`. It works but I don't like this workaround.

So, any suggestions is appriciated.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [GwtMockito](https://google.github.io/gwtmockito/)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying out GwtMockito now, but I still have other problems